# What would an update mechanism look like in bash

Tags: linux, bash, script

I have to update a script compilation from time to time but I haven't any idea how to start a version check script in bash.

I've got a version file with 3 vars: `version=0`, `subversion=0` and `subsubversion=1` and I've got a web server that serves the updates with install routines as bash scripts. In a directory called updates:

```
/updates/
0.0.1
0.0.2
0.0.3
```

and a directory called current where the current version is stored.

```
/current/
0.0.1
version
```

Now I'd like to have a script that takes `$version`, `$subversion` and `$subsubversion` and determines witch update to download and execute. After this part has finished the update script should increment a var so that it downloads the next update if it is available. Let's call it `nextversion`.

I stuck with incrementing the three vars and the`nextversion` variable in the update script.

What could I do to increment the tree vars and a fourth var to the next higher level. How do I handle it if I go from 0.0.9 to 0.1.0 or even from 0.9.9 to 1.0.0 and so on. Without producing a lot of `if`-`else`-`elif` statements. I'm sadly not good in figuring out loops.

Comment: Version numbers are just numbers. So after `0.9.0` you of course can also have a `0.10.0`. But if you want to make things easy, just use something like a revision number which you simply count up. So just stick to `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`, and so on.

Comment: This sounds like a really inefficient way to do the updating -- if a particular script has been updated 10 times between the version on the client and the latest one, should it really download each of the 9 intermediate versions in sequence?

Comment: Basically it should be able to update the system regardless witch version is installed. I haven't any idea how to use git for this.  If I had I would use it instead of bash.

Answer (score 0):

This breaks after 9.9.9

```
#!/bin/bash

version=0
subversion=0
subsubversion=1

updateVersion()
{
  if [ "$subsubversion" -lt 9 ]; then
    subsubversion=$((subsubversion+1));
  elif [ "$subsubversion" = 9 ] && [ "$subversion" -lt 9 ]; then
    subsubversion="0"; subversion=$((subversion+1));
  elif [ "$subsubversion" = 9 ] && [ "$subversion" = 9 ] && [ "$version" -lt 9 ]; then
    subsubversion="0"; subversion="0"; version=$((version+1));
  else
    echo "overflow"
  fi
}

printVersion()
{
  echo "${version}.${subversion}.${subsubversion}";
}

updateVersion
printVersion
```

Perhaps you'd rather use git instead?